# Python Tkinter sides

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. I'm trying to setup a simple clock with the date on top and the time on the bottom. If I swap the side of the topFrame and bottomFrame it fixes it but that doesn't make sense to me. I feel like I'm just missing something simple.

[Code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1fZW.jpg)

Comment: Can I suggest you post your code as text, rather than an image? It will make it much simpler for others to run your code.

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site, and _definitely_ don't link to screenshots of code.

Comment: Well you cant post images until you get a certain amount of reputation points so it automatically post it to imgur instead...

Answer (score 0):

[From a website I found](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm):

> **side**= Specifies which side to pack the widget against. To pack widgets
>   vertically, use TOP (default). To pack widgets horizontally, use LEFT.
>   You can also pack widgets along the BOTTOM and RIGHT edges. **You can
>   mix sides in a single geometry manager, but the results may not always
>   be what you expect.** While you can create pretty complicated layouts by
>   nesting Frame widgets, you may prefer using the grid geometry manager
>   for non-trivial layouts.

So for your code, I would try:

```
date.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
clock.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
```

Even though you are using `TOP` for both, they stack in the order upon which you place them, so `date` goes to the top, then `clock` goes to the bottom of date.

EDIT: Another example can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/LayoutsideTOPLEFT.htm)

---

I think the problem you are having now is using multiple frames. Try this:

```
fm = Frame(root)
data = Label(fm, font=('ariel', 20, 'bold'), bg='black', fg='white')
clock = Label(fm, font=('ariel', 20, 'bold'), bg='black', fg='white')

date.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
clock.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't change. It only seems to change if I put topFrame on bottom and/or bottomFrame on top which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think the edit will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue. Due to lack of attention I didn't notice that the problem wasn't with the packing or sides. It's because I was using date for the clock variable and time for the date variable.

I was using:
    date2 = time.strftime('%I:%S %p')
    time2 = time.strftime('%A, %B %d %Y')
Instead of:
    time2 = time.strftime('%I:%S %p')
    date2 = time.strftime('%A, %B %d %Y')

I appreciate everyone help though!